# Android tag questions out of sync around page 20 (pagination)

Tags: bug, tags, pagination

Marching through Android questions yields a bizarre gap around page 20 with *page size = 50* and *sort = newest* at the moment:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?page=20&sort=newest&pagesize=50

If one were to start around page 18 and move forward, you would see the dates drop clearly out of range by several days at least.

It is as if the linked list or pagination technique has gone astray.

Around page 30, questions from April of 2015 appear. One should have to traverse several hundred pages (of 50 per page) before depleting April of 2016 alone.

Hopefully it is a very localized data problem that can be patched.

Edit1:

page 13 of Java. Pagination broken
 [image]
Is there any commentary available from the SO dev team on this? The problem is intermittent.

Comment: To further the point, at page 22 for example, there are 50 questions spanning a month, which is very unlikely considering that page 1 has 50 questions spanning 2 hours.

Comment: Do you have the new nav enabled?

Comment: @hichris123 not that I am aware. But several of us in socvr chat confirmed it

Comment: In fact it was first seen via a non-authenticated bot of mine

Comment: Yeh android posts are prolific, and have been for a while. it's unlikely they'd drop off suddenly.

Comment: it's like it wants to start rushing through them all the further along you go

Comment: Any chance there was a calendar change around that date? :-D

Comment: Well, some questions get deleted so if you look in the past you *should* see less posts on average due to this, even if the rate was exactly the same... however I don't think such a change can be attributed to this factor alone.

Comment: This is not reproducible now, but I've also experienced this. I use an active question list of my favorite tags (15 tags with `or` in between them) and sometimes after I reload the page, the bottom 5 to 10 question of the first page are up to 6 years old. No idea how to reproduce for others, but it happens regularly.

Comment: I just ran thru page numbers 20 to 50. It seems to have healed itself. One of my bots marches thru tags to update external systems. Have done this probably on close to 150k pages and have not noticed this before. So it was not an issue of a question getting deleted, but rather of an upset apple cart so to speak.

Comment: @ArtjomB. for active questions I can understand that if there is new activity. But for newest, the dates were all helter skelter

Comment: @Drew Yes, I mean sorted by newest.

Comment: Re: "One of my bots marches through tags". Why don't you use the API instead?

Comment: I use both mechanisms. The point is not that, but rather fear of pockets of unreachable questions. Not fear of my not finding them, but others

Comment: It's getting worse. Just now, my page 7 (50 per) jumps from 9 hrs ago, to 10, 12, 16, 18, then 2 days ago. This is not good. How am I supposed to review the last days' posts?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks. This [here](http://i.imgur.com/AJ4w4JR.jpg) was the top of page 8 a few minutes ago. Question #36894377 ... [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894377) . No way in the world that belongs in that pagination flow

Comment: At 700 questions a day, I estimate that 3pm UTC 2 days ago question should be nestled somewhere around page 30

Comment: I just scanned pages 1 to 49. I noticed on the top of page 12 an Oct 2014 question was at the top. Note, it was inserting the question id's into a db table as the process went along. At the end, I did a count of questions in year 2014. Answer was 50. The min(askDate) was `2009-03-01 18:09:09` so the whole thing is messed up. I can publish the sheet somewhere if someone wants it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have pushed a "reload" instruction to the servers, which will hopefully fix this for now, but we are aware that this is an occasional bug. The good news is that we are in the process of completely overhauling the code that drives this, which should resolve a range of stability and performance issues, while also removing a metric ton of tech debt that has accrued in this code. The best thing I can say in the defence of the v1 code is that it grew organically... like mould. The v2 codebase has been lovingly crafted from the ground up with full knowledge of what the eventual requirements and use-cases would be, which makes a big difference!

Comment: Thanks Marc. Glad you are aware, have ways to lessen the impact, and a fix is on the radar sometime.